# Disable dockerd at startup

Tags: debian, startup, docker

I am using docker sparsely. I don't need the daemon to be running all the time. I would like to disable it from starting up automatically.

I tried doing :

```
sudo systemctl disable docker
```

but it still shows up.

[image]

I am running debian 8.

Docker seems to take a long time to close, and so my shutdown times are much longer. I just want to disable the docker daemon from starting automatically on boot

Comment: Are you sure it still autostarts *after reboot*? Cause the command you've used is a correct one. UPDATE: if you expected that docker would stop immediately after running disable - nope. Then you have also to `systemctl stop` it.

Comment: The picture I sent is after a boot . And it has the dockerd processes. If I do service dockerd stop then they all go away

Comment: hm, that's weird. Are you sure you don't start it elsewhere?

Comment: I don't manually start it. I don't know how to check where else it may be starting

Comment: Try looking up `journalctl` searching for "docker" for some insights on what is run during the startup.

Comment: so i just discovered that i was also running nvidia-docker, which was enabled. doing a systemctl disable nvidia-docker fixed the problem

Comment: glad the issue is solved!

Comment: In my case, I had to disable `docker-volume-local-persist.service` and `docker.socket`, as well. To list any *docker* service in systemd, type: `systemctl list-unit-files | grep -i docker`